# How to save image from NSData after doing the action of appendData?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to save image from NSdata after appending additional bytes to the NSMutableData. Below is the sample code for my requirement.

```
NSData *sourceData = = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"], 1);

NSMutableData *concatenatedData = [NSMutableData data];
[concatenatedData appendData:sourceData];
[concatenatedData appendData:sourceData];

UIImage *myFinalImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:concatenatedData]; 
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myFinalImage, self, nil, nil);
```

I am appending the sourcedata 2 times but my final Image is saving with only one sourceData bytes.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: [concatenatedData appendData:sourceData]; why 2 times ?

Comment: do you want to merge two images and create it as one image??

Comment: Are you expecting two images? This won't happen by this way.

Comment: Exactly.... That is my requirement...

Comment: @Ashwin: yes I am expecting the final saved image should contains the image twice. Which approach I need to follow ?

Comment: Wait.. this is possible.

Comment: @PKCoder: My requirement is to save image with appendData Bytes. Please dont provided misleading links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Sample:

```
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake({Here give width}, {Here give height});
     UIImage *myFinalImage1 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:concatenatedData]; 
      UIImage *myFinalImage2 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:concatenatedData]; 

        // Set up width height with values.
        CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );

        [myFinalImage1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

        [myFinalImage2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(newSize.width,newSize.height,newSize.width,newSize.height*2) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

        UIImage *mergedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: This is a sample to approach the result. What do you mean by "new Size"? I have updated sample.

Comment: [myFinalImage1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)]; , myFinalImage1 will cover complete newSize bound...